# Rails - Creating temp files in a portable way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, temporary-files

My rails application runs on a Ubuntu server machine.

I need to create temporary files in order to "feed" them to a second, independent app (I'll be using rake tasks for this, in case this information is needed)

My question is: what is the best way of creating temporary fields on a rails application?

Since I'm in ubuntu, I could create them on `/tmp/whatever`, but what would work only in linux.

I'd like my application to be as portable as possible - so it can be installed on Windows machines & mac, if needed.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`tmp/` is definitively the right place to put the files.

The best way I've found of creating files on that folder is using [ruby's tempfile library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/index.html).

The code looks like this:

```
require 'tempfile'

def foo()
  # creates a temporary file in tmp/
  Tempfile.open('prefix', Rails.root.join('tmp') ) do |f|
    f.print('a temp message')
    f.flush
    #... do more stuff with f
  end
end
```

I like this solution because:

- It generates random file names automatically (you can provide a prefix)
- It automatically deletes the files when they are no longer used. For example, if invoked on a rake task, the files are removed when the rake task ends.

Comment: Cool, what a useful abstraction.

Comment: `file.path` to refer to the tmp file if you are looking for it !

Answer (score 7):

Rails apps also have their own `tmp/` directory. I guess that one is always available and thus a good candidate to use and keep your application portable.